# Is Sign In With Apple ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential.user linked to user Identity?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, oauth-2.0

If Im authenticating a user via Sign In With Apple and using `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential.user` to identify the user that I get back via `func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization)`  , in the App Privacy disclosure do you need to select that the collected Identifiers are linked to user Identity or not?